# Python requests module suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, module, python-requests

I am new to python and I have imported a couple modules for a script I am working on and one of them is requests. After a couple of weeks testing my script with no issues all of sudden in stop working and the message below appears.

I manually installed requests and didn't install any other module. The last thing I did is do some import command on the python shell to test if it is available.

```
[a.panaglima]$ ./downloader_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./downloader_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import time, datetime, requests, base64, urllib2, urllib, json
  File "/home/SRL/a.panaglima/time.py", line 2, in <module>
    import time, datetime, requests, base64, urllib2, urllib, json
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.6.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 63, in load_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    _startTime = time.time()
```

Comment: Did you miss a line or lines at the bottom of the traceback?

Comment: Your traceback looks incomplete. Also, can you show us the contents of the downloader_test.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a file `time.py` (`/home/SRL/a.panaglima/time.py`) that is causing issues shadowing the built-in time module.

Remove/rename this file.

Alternatively, refactor your project and use `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of your file (above other imports).  [This became standard in <strike>2.7</strike> Python3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports)